# Statistics on life expectancies

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I don't understand how to solve the last the questions of this problem. Can anybody help me with this.

[The table shows the life expectancies of a child (at birth) in the United States for selected years from 1940 through 2010. (Source: U.S. National Center for Health Statistics)

- 1940 - 62.9
- 1950 - 68.2
- 1960 - 69.7
- 1970 - 70.8
- 1980 - 73.7
- 1990 - 75.4
- 2000 - 76.8
- 2010 - 78.7

A model for the life expectancy during this period is 
y = (63.6 + 0.97t)/ (1 + 0.01t) , 0≤t≤70

where y represents the life expectancy and t is the time in years, with t = 0 corresponding to 1940. 
(a) Use a graphing utility 
to graph the data 
from the table 
and the model 
in the same 
viewing window. 
How well does 
the model fit the 
data? Explain. 
(b) Determine the life expectancy in 1990 both graphically and algebraically. 
(c) Use the graph to determine the year when life expectancy was approximately 70.1. Verify your answer algebraically. 
(d) Find the y-intercept of the graph of the model. What does it represent in the context of the problem? 
(e) Do you think this model can be used to predict the life expectancy of a child 50 years from now? Explain.

Comment: I think the model needs some editing. Is there a square missing?

Comment: It seems that there is a typo in $0.97t/ 1 + 0.01t $. Are parentheses missing? Or is it 1/t instead of t/1 ?

Comment: I have checked and added the parentheses.

Comment: No. I looked at it. This is the model

Comment: Please help me with this...

Comment: Regarding (e) you could compute the prediction using the model, and discuss its plausibility given you knowledge and understanding of the model and how it has been estimated.

Comment: Regarding (e), ask yourself if conditions affecting life expectancy in the USA fifty years from now will be the same, or nearly the same, as those now.  What do you think?